# Marketing Cloud Journey Builder Contacts

Tags: journeybuilder, data-export, contactbuilder

Is there a way to export contacts from the Journey Builder activity? Started off with 44k contacts, now have 43K that have not taken any action to exit the journey. How can those 43K be exported?

Comment: Similar question:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000COjOQAW

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more specific ? In general, you can access Journey Builder history and log data by API [Is there a way to retrieve Journey History for contact using REST API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171719/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-journey-history-for-contact-using-rest-api/193939#193939)