# Access Granular Contact Journey Builder History Via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have Salesforce and Marketing Cloud (MC) and use the MC sync between them. My boss would like to allow Marketing to see MC Journey info for a contact when viewing a Salesforce contact record. Ideally, the marketer would see which journeys the contact is in, which part of the journey, and what messages have been sent.

I'm researching the MC APIs to see what's available and it seems much of this isn't available. This [Contact Membership](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/contactMembershipRequest.htm) will show which journeys a contact is in and the journey version. This [older post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171719/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-journey-history-for-contact-using-rest-api) indicates it's not available and using undocumented features is not a path I want to explore. Are there other options to get this data via API?

Answer (score 1):

Given you've got Marketing Cloud Connect in place, you'd probably make use of this free App Exchange app from Salesforce Labs which does exactly what you're looking for: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FZBjRUAX

Once set up, you're able to install a Marketing Cloud Journeys component on your Contact page layout, showing you any journeys the contact is in and which version. It also allows you to stop a journey for a given contact, directly from Sales/Service Cloud.

Seeing which emails have been sent to a contact should already be in place through your Marketing Cloud Connect setup, with tracking results for Journey Builder sends passed to Sales/Service Cloud.