# Journey Activity View timestamp of activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

In **Journey Builder** there is **Journey History**, this view is random order and I have 3000+ records. Making it incredibly difficult to try and figure out the flow.

My plan was to join [Journey](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5) and [Journey Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5) views. This was a partial success because i get the `ActivityID`, `ActivityName`, `ActivityExternalKey` and `JourneyActivityObjectID` and `ActivityType`. But there is no `timestamp` field. There is one in the Journey History from JB but nothing in the views. Is there another view I can join on or an undocumented field?

**Objective**: Extract Similar data as Journey History but be able to sort it for troubleshooting :)

Thanks

Comment: this information isn't currently in any of the dataviews, you could look at leveraging the journey history route: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171719/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-journey-history-for-contact-using-rest-api

Comment: The last edit on the accepted answer says to use Journey Activity View. Rather strange that the view doesn't have the transaction timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set up a data extension for tracking, and insert Update Contact activities into your journey at each milestone that you want to track. You'll only have the most recent row per subscriber though, since it updates rather than appending.